# Отключить оформление ошибок XDebug

Tags: php, xdebug

Собственно, как это сделать без отключения самого XDebug?

[image: пример]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877817/how-to-enable-formatted-xdebug-errors-and-traces

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.